# Explaination of how Wallis's formula was used to arrive at the end result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

While looking for a proof on Stirling's formula I am having a little trouble connecting the dots between these last two steps here:
[1]: [image: a busy cat]
!

The first formula is Wallis's formula.

Comment: The last expression is Wallis's formula rewritten, after simplifying the double factorials in the numerator and denominator: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Comment: Multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $(2n)!!$, we get $$\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!} =\frac{(2n)!!(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!(2n)!!} = \frac{[(2n)!!]^2}{(2n)!} = \frac{(2^n n!)^2}{(2n)!}.$$

Comment: Thank you! filling up characters.